# Add premium to WooCommerce price

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to apply a premium on the Canadian side of my site (it uses USD and CAD). So far I've tried this with no luck in functions.php, just to see if anything changes...but it just removes the price altogether on some pages and makes it 0 on others. I should note that we are unfortunately using an older version of WooCommerce at the moment (version 2.5.5)

```
function jwd_manage_price_premium( $price ) {
        $price = $price * 1000;
        return $price;
    }
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'jwd_manage_price_premium' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'jwd_manage_price_premium' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to isolate the price and currency using the following. I had to remove some HTML. It seems so inefficient, though. I suppose the newer version of WooCommerce (hopefully) has a better way to modify prices.

```html
function jwd_manage_price_premium( $price ) {
    $stripped = strip_tags($price);
    $stripped = str_replace("class=\"amount\">", "", $stripped);
    $split = explode( " " , $stripped );
    $number = $split[0];
    $currency = $split[2];
    var_dump($split);
    echo "<br>";
  return $price;
 }
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'jwd_manage_price_premium' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'jwd_manage_price_premium' );
```